# Motorcycle Gas Pump Auto Shut-Off

Tags: motorcycle, gasoline, fuel-tank

Are the [automatic shut-off](http://auto.howstuffworks.com/gas-pump5.htm) systems at gas stations compatible with motorcycle gas tanks?

Specifically, the [2017 Honda Rebel 500](https://powersports.honda.com/2017/rebel-500.aspx), which is a cruiser with a 2.96 gallon gas tank.

[Here is a video](https://youtu.be/L-wavKwE5qY?t=2m35s) of a guy filling up the tank for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they are.  Next time you're at the pump, before you turn it on, pull out the nozzle and inspect the tip of it.  There will be a small hole or sensing port.  When this hole starts to suck gas, the pump clicks off.

[image]

When filling, however, I normally don't rely on this because if you insert the entire nozzle and wait for the auto shut-off, you're leaving quite a bit of room in the tank.

Begin to fill at full speed with the nozzle mostly inserted until you think the tank is getting full, or the auto shut off kicks in.  Then pull out the nozzle some until you can see the level of fuel and slowly fill the rest of the way until you see the fuel at the top.

Comment: Some places have a safety sleeve as well so that the sleeve must be pulled back for gas to flow.

Comment: Right. The sleeves that I've seen are actually for vapor recovery.  The idea is that the rubber sleeve sucks in the air escaping the tank so less fuel vapor is released.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean by "compatible."

For my bike (here in Southern California at least), the auto-shutoff will kick if I just insert the nozzle and pull the trigger. **However**, this doesn't result in a full tank.

So to that degree, it will kick itself, but not at a full tank like with a car/truck. [This explains](http://auto.howstuffworks.com/gas-pump5.htm) how the shutoff mechanism works. Since cars and trucks have a pipe that channels the gas down to the tank, you will get a full tank ***before*** the fuel starts moving up the pipe and shutting off at the nozzle. Whenever you're filling directly into the tank (same is true with gas cans) though,  the nozzle protrudes into the same chamber and will shutoff at the level when the end of the nozzle sits.

Anyway, I hope that kind of answer the question. :)