# How does the pump know the tank is full?

Tags: gasoline, fuel-tank

Question has been bothering me a while.

When putting fuel at any gas station, when the tank is almost full, the pump just stops and makes a 'THUNK' noise.

I was wondering... how the hell does the pump knows the tank is almost full? There doesnt seem to be a probe that when the fuel touches it it stops the pump, and you can always put a little bit more and be ok...

So how does the pump know how to stop itself?

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate question, but not quite: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/46967/12030 . There is a "probe".  It's the gas pump nozzle sticking into the filler neck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple explanation:

Gas pump handles use air pressure to monitor when to shut off. There is a small tube in the nozzle that when foam or fuel blocks it causes the pressure to change and trips the shutoff.

Detailed explanation (with video):

[How does a gas pump know when my tank is full?](https://auto.howstuffworks.com/fuel-efficiency/fuel-consumption/gas-pump-full-tank.htm)